# Having trouble getting the future date?

Tags: java, date

```
        Date now = taskExecutionDate;
        taskNextRunTime = task.getNextRunTime();
        long delta = taskNextRunTime - now.getTime();

        log.debug("now.getTime() = " + now.getTime() + ", " + now);
        log.debug("taskNextRunTime = " + taskNextRunTime + ", " + new Date(taskNextRunTime));
        log.debug("now.getTime() = " + now.getTime() + ", " + now);
            log.debug("taskNextRunTime = " + taskNextRunTime + ", " + new Date(taskNextRunTime));
            log.debug("delta = " + delta);
            log.debug("endDate = " + task.getEndDate());
            log.debug("startDate = " + task.getStartDate());
            if(task.getEndDate().equals(task.getStartDate())){
                taskNextRunTime = task.getNextRunTime();
                log.debug("taskNextRunTime in = " + taskNextRunTime + ", " + new Date(taskNextRunTime));

            }
```

My log files shows this:

```
    now.getTime() = 1440518657145, Tue Aug 25 12:04:17 EDT 2015
    taskNextRunTime = 0, Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
    delta = -1440518657145
    endDate = Tue Aug 25 23:59:00 EDT 2015
    startDate = Tue Aug 25 00:00:01 EDT 2015
```

I don't have access to the source code task.class. I've been trying to find out a work around but haven't been able to. How can I go by getting the date in the future or if there is a work around? Any help appreciated.

Update: Task.class method:

```
    public long getNextRunTime();
0  aload_0 [this]
1  invokestatic java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() : long [24]
4  invokevirtual task.Task.getNextRunTime(long) : long [25]
7  lreturn
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 239]



  // Method descriptor #141 (J)J
  // Stack: 4, Locals: 7
  public long getNextRunTime(long arg0);
 0  aload_0 [this]
 1  invokevirtual task.Task.getEndDate() : java.util.Date [26]
 4  ifnull 21
 7  aload_0 [this]
 8  invokevirtual task.Task.getEndDate() : java.util.Date [26]
11  invokevirtual java.util.Date.getTime() : long [27]
14  lload_1 [arg0]
15  lcmp
16  ifge 21
19  lconst_0
20  lreturn
21  aload_0 [this]
22  invokevirtual task.Task.getStartDate() : java.util.Date [28]
25  invokevirtual java.util.Date.getTime() : long [27]
28  lload_1 [arg0]
29  invokestatic java.lang.Math.max(long, long) : long [29]
32  lstore_3
33  aload_0 [this]
34  invokevirtual task.Task.getSchedule() : task.Schedule [30]
37  lload_3
38  aload_0 [this]
39  invokevirtual task.Task.getStartDate() : java.util.Date [28]
42  invokevirtual .task.Schedule.getNextRunTimeFrom(long, java.util.Date) : long [31]
45  lstore 5
47  aload_0 [this]
48  invokevirtual task.Task.getEndDate() : java.util.Date [26]
51  ifnull 69
54  aload_0 [this]
55  invokevirtual task.Task.getEndDate() : java.util.Date [26]
58  invokevirtual java.util.Date.getTime() : long [27]
61  lload 5
63  lcmp
64  ifge 69
67  lconst_0
68  lreturn
69  lload 5
71  lreturn
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 251]
    [pc: 19, line: 253]
    [pc: 21, line: 258]
    [pc: 33, line: 261]
    [pc: 47, line: 265]
    [pc: 67, line: 267]
    [pc: 69, line: 270]
  Stack map table: number of frames 2
    [pc: 21, same]
    [pc: 69, append: {long, long}]
```

My desired output is to get the future date i.e. taskNextRunTime. Whenever the user select a date/time in future, it is saved in taskNextRunTime, but when I check my logs it's always taskNextRunTime = 0, Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969. now.getTime works fine, but task.getNextRunTime() gives me Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969 instead of the date selected in the future.

Comment: You problem is the `task` class so if you don't have access to this code or class you will need to find someone who does.

Comment: @PeterLawrey updated with the relevant code.

Comment: Peter is probably right, but you should also describe your problem in more detail - what exactly is your desired output? Explain how this differs from your current input, explain which line is giving the wrong value and why you can't fix it - pretty much any detail which could at all be useful and might seem obvious - the less time we have to spend figuring out what's going on with your code and what you're asking, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Comment: @Dukeling updated my question.

Comment: This is calling `getNextRunTime(long)` do you have the code for that?  I use the decompiler in IntelliJ and that does a pretty good job, even creating code with original line numbers.

Comment: @PeterLawrey updated. Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: @Jay When you debug the code, can you see the values of the start date, end date and schedule?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes. I have attached the output above form my log files for the start date and end date. If a user selects a time in future, the startDate and endDate just gets the date and time, like in the case above it's the same day.

Comment: taskNextRunTime is suppose to get the future time and date which it doesn't and instead always gets Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969.

Comment: @Jay There is two conditions which return `0` which you are turning into `new Date(0)` which prints as the date you see.  One of those conditions is returning 0.

Comment: Most likely `.task.Schedule.getNextRunTimeFrom(long, java.util.Date) > task.Task.getEndDate()` in which case the method return 0.

Comment: @PeterLawrey can there be a work around for this?

Comment: Make sure the getNextRunTimeFrom is less than the getEndDate.

Comment: I've tried that and the only case it's greater is when the end date is different than the startDate. That works, but what I'm trying to fix is to get it to run if a future time is on the same day i.e. the same start date and end date. Any thoughts on a work around for that?